# What is the sequence of thread execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I have been recently trying to wrap my head around multithreading and understand how it works. I have some example code here but I cannot understand why the output is the way it is.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>   

using namespace std;   


std::mutex mtx;
int global_counter = 0;
std::mutex counter_mutex;   

void five_thread_fn(){
   for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
       counter_mutex.lock();
       global_counter++;
       std::cout << "Updated from five_thread"  << endl;
       counter_mutex.unlock();
       // std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
   }
   //When this thread finishes we wait for it to join
}   

void ten_thread_fn(){
   for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
       counter_mutex.lock();
       global_counter++;
       std::cout << "Updated from ten_thread"  << endl;
       counter_mutex.unlock();
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
   }
   //When this thread finishes we wait for it to join
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


   std::cout << "starting thread ten..." << std::endl;
   std::thread ten_thread(ten_thread_fn);

   std::cout << "Starting thread five..." << endl;
   std::thread five_thread(five_thread_fn);   


   five_thread.join();
   std::cout << "Five Thread is done." << std::endl;
   ten_thread.join();   

   std::cout << "Ten Thread is done." << std::endl;



   // std::cin.ignore();   

   return 0;


}
```

I have commented out the time delays in the threads and here is my output:

```
Starting thread ten...
Starting thread five...
Updated from five_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from five_thread
Updated from five_thread
Updated from five_thread
Updated from five_thread
Five Thread is done.
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Updated from ten_thread
Ten Thread is done.
```

Now I am wondering why does "updated from ten_thread" appear after the first line of "updated from five_thread"?

In the main function when I do

```
five_thread.join();
```

Does that not suspend the main thread until five_thread completes its execution?

To my understanding, it is only after the five_thread finishes that the lines after five_thread.join() execute (sequentially). So how is the ten_thread being called in between?

Is the execution of the lines of code in main() not sequential?

Comment: The `ten_thread` is not the main thread. You have **3** threads in that program and the only one being made to wait is the main thread. Both the `five_thread` and the `ten_thread` run concurrently with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that not suspend the main thread until five_thread completes its execution?

Yes. But the fact that A is waiting on B does not somehow stop C from doing its own thing on its own time. Joining a thread does not give that thread priority in terms of execution. It doesn't mean that the thread being joined will *start* at that point.

Concurrent execution means *concurrent* execution. There is no order between the execution of concurrent things unless you *explicitly* give it one. Joining a thread only states that the current thread will resume after the given one has completed.

Comment: Ok so then "updated from ten_thread" happens and since that thread has a wait time for 1 second, the "updated from five_thread" appear consecutively really fast within that 1 second. Because ten_thread hasn't exactly stopped but it is just waiting. Meaning it is still "going" at the same time as five_thread. Thank you, I understand now. I tested without the time delay and the messages get printed out in alternating order from each other.

Answer (score 1):

> To my understanding, it is only after the five_thread finishes that
>   the lines after five_thread.join() execute (sequentially). So how is
>   the ten_thread being called in between?

Because that thread has already been started.

```
std::thread ten_thread(ten_thread_fn);
```

This starts the execution thread. `ten_thread()` is not being called "in between" of anything. It is an independent execution thread, that executes concurrently with all other threads.

The thread gets started when `std::thread` gets instantiated, and continues executing while the main thread goes along its business.

All that `join()` does is pause the main execution thread until the given execution thread terminates. That execution thread is already running, concurrently.

As soon as `ten_thread` gets instantiated, it means that `ten_thread_fn()` is executing, loosely speaking.

Comment: I see, now I understand when the execution begins. Thank you!